# Option to order unanswered questions by fewest views per time?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, sorting, question-order

I have a few unanswered questions at stackoverflow. The most recent one is two days old and has two views, one view per day. This makes me think that the reason the question is unanswered is not that no one knows the answer, but that no one has seen the question.

Out of curiosity I looked at the unanswered questions section at stackoverflow to see how many unnoticed questions like mines were out there, but I did not find any support in the UI to identify such questions.

I suggest that you add the possibility to order unanswered questions by fewest views per time. This way it would be easy for the community to find the questions that hasn't been noticed and had to wait for an answer for too long.

Comment: maybe you should change the title to start with "Option to..."

Comment: I just changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are reasons these questions get no love.  If you were given the questions in this sort order, it is highly unlikely you would be able to answer any of them, and if you could, it would take major research.

I have considered doing the research and posting Eric-Lippert-quality answers on some of these questions, just to see how much long-tail rep I could get.  Unfortunately, my attention span is not that long and...What was the question again?

Comment: The question that I was referring to was this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045937/how-can-i-see-the-entire-scm-history-in-my-xcode-project

Comment: If a question has many views, but no answers, then it might be because the question is too hard. If the question has no answers and no views, it might just be that no one has seen the question. Also if someone looks at a question in the view it would be moved further down the list, so it would always be the questions that has been shown the least attention that turns up in this view.